# Reduce number of dependiencies in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm running a pyspark streaming job. For each rdd I update a temporary table with some new data that I want to cache, like below:

```
def forach_rdd(rdd):
    sqlContext = SQLContext(rdd.context)
    cached_data_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE UPDATED_ON >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR")

    external_df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
        url=config.value.get('host'),
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        user=config.value.get('username'),
        password=config.value.get('password'),
        fetchsize=25000,
        query="SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE /*SOME THRESHOLD FOR NEW VALUES*/"
    ).load()

    union_df = cached_data_df.union(external_df).coalesce(3).cache()
    union_df.createOrReplaceTempView('temp_table')

    # operate on union_df 

DStream.foreachRDD(forach_rdd)
```

After few hours, the spark job crashes, because of a stack overflow ;)
The reason is most likely related to growing tree of rdd dependencies underneath a dataframe.

My question is: How can I force spark, to create new dataframe with updated data, but without dependency history.

I suppose something like below would work, but it doesn't seem very efficient:

```
sc.parallelize(union_df.collect()).toDF(union_df.schema)
```

Is there any better way of doing this? I would welcome any hints.

[edit] I uploaded the exception stack trace to pastebin, since it's a bit long:
https://pastebin.com/raw/3sPNdyUa

Comment: can you also post the stackoverflow exception's stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Start by replacing your caching with an eager checkpoint:

```
union_df = cached_data_df.union(external_df).coalesce(3).checkpoint(True)
```

This will alleviate your issue temporarily, but you should set up more robust checkpointing for streaming. [Take a look at the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing).